# Best practice: Storing Authentication Information in Backend

Tags: python, security, authentication, oauth-2.0, fastapi

I am developing a FastAI backend which uses a 3rd party authentication. The performance of this authentication method is horrible. Every token validation takes multiple seconds.

Therefore, I am considering to set up a backend session information system which stores every token + validity which has been checked once and validate a token which is received from the frontend in my backend environment based on the cookies.

I don't see any risk in, but at the same time this seems to be quite off from a best practice. I would appreciate any advice if such a setup is reasonable?

Comment: What kind of tokens are we talking about? JWTs or other tokens? The main issue is that you might not catch a token revocation if you're not checking them, but you usually work around that by having a period defined in which you assume a token is valid regardless (as would be necessary for a JWT). Checking if the token is still valid every ten-fifteen minutes would usually be good enough, and then _actually_ checking it if the user performs a destructive or sensitive operation.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. We are talking about a JWT token. 

I will (a) seperate the endpoits and validate whenever critical and (b) validate every 5 minutes.

Comment: JWT tokens are meant to have everything you need to _not_ revalidate it for every request (which is why they have everything built-in and a signature to verify its authenticity). This comes with the caveat that you can't expire a token easily, since you don't verify that is valid for each request - but instead check that the token hasn't expired (which is embedded in the token itself). This expire time is then set to a value that is low enough for your use case, and you can then verify that it hasn't been deactivated for destructive operations.